# Highcharts export in firefox giving black background for plotbands

Tags: firefox, highcharts

I am having trouble with a "Print" option in highcharts.js (using Firefox browser). Since the background it initially gave me was black, I added an option

```
chart: {
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
},
```

which solves the initial problem. However, my plotbands still remain black.

Here is a fiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/1qr8ousa/1/

Comment: It seems it has a problem with the default color, so it would make sense to just add a default plotband, like `{color: '#fff',from: 6.5,to: 1/0}` (http://jsfiddle.net/c59xLzeo/1/) - does it break anything?

Comment: @kikon unfortunately, it does not seem to solve the problem since the plotband we've tried to add is being exported as a black one as well, therefore making the background of the entire chart black

Comment: I was getting black only for the area right to 6.5 - firefox, chrome, edge all on mac

Comment: @kikon it seems I had an unchecked box  "Print backgrounds" in the Firefox's "More settings" after clicking on "Print". This seems to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: And now I see that it was not actually black, but transparent that appeared black